# Conda not recognizing that I have node installed?

Tags: node.js, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

I open the terminal.

`jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/github`

```
An error occured.
ValueError: Please install nodejs >=10.0.0 before continuing. nodejs may be installed using conda or directly from the nodejs website.
See the log file for details
```

Yet:

`node -v`

`v14.5.0`

What's going on, and how do I make conda find my node?

Comment: YES
Thomas' answer fixed the problem for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63189295/1959325

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I had a similar problem and it was solved after I installed the [full package](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nodejs):

> To install this package with conda run one of the following:
>
> ```
> conda install -c conda-forge nodejs
> conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 nodejs
> conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 nodejs
> conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 nodejs
> ```

Comment: Full package?  As in you ran one of those installs or all?  I ran the first line `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs` successfully, but it still doesn't budge.

Comment: NOTE: The documentation at 'full package' mentioned above , says "To install this package with conda run ONE of the following".

Comment: does't this just installs nodejs four times from different sources, remove each  time the one installed with the previous command? If you run these four, it's the same as just running the last line

Comment: This installs different versions of node.js. I found that the last line installs the latest version available via conda. v12.4.0

Comment: This answer solves my problem with installing extensions (Many thanks!). Installing just the top line isn't sufficient.

Comment: Thanks! Only the last line worked for some reason.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. The problem was I installed nodejs both with [my conda package manager](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/nodejs) and in [my system](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md). I removed one of them (the conda nodejs package) and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was solved by installing it from the jupyter's `terminal` instead of firing off command from within the notebook.

Answer (score 0):

run this command inside Jupiter terminal
"conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 nodejs"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).